# Scala: Generate Companion Objects

Tags: scala, companion-object

Is there anyway to automatically generate a companion object for every subclass of a certain class?

For example, I have a `class Component[T]` which has a `val companion: CompType[T]` where `T` should be the subclass. For example: `class Transform extends Component[Transform]`.

Is there any way at all to have the companion objects for each subclass to be generated - petty though it seems - to save typing out the object definition for every kind of Component I make?

**EDIT:**

The end goal of all this is an entity-system. Each companion object has a unique integer (that it gets from an inherited trait) that can be used to look up a component of that specific type from an array of components. So for example, if I want to add a Transform component to an entity, I would call:

```
addComponent(entity, Transform, new Transform(params))
```

The new `Transform` object would then be placed in the array of components representing the entity at the index provided by the Transform companion object. But since the companion objects get their indices from the trait they inherit, there is no typed-out difference between any of them apart from their names. Hence why it would be nice to have them generated.

Sorry for not being more specific to begin with. If this is still confusing, it may well be that I'm just doing this the complete wrong way! Feel free to tell me that if you think so.

Comment: What would these companion object contain? What do you need them for?

Comment: Sorry I really should have mentioned that. I wanted to keep the question relatively short. I'll edit and add more detail.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that there's any way to automatically generate companion objects in Scala as it currently stands. The upcoming macro type support might help you eventually, but that's still in development.

If I understand you correctly, the companion object only exists to provide a per-class unique integer? In which case, perhaps something like this would work?

```
scala> object UniqueNumberProvider {
     |   val numbers = new collection.mutable.HashMap[Class[_], Int]
     |   def numberForClass(clazz: Class[_]) = numbers.get(clazz) match {
     |     case Some(n) => n
     |     case None => numbers.update(clazz, numbers.size + 1); numbers.size
     |   }
     | }
defined module UniqueNumberProvider

scala> UniqueNumberProvider.numberForClass(classOf[String])
res7: Int = 1

scala> UniqueNumberProvider.numberForClass(classOf[String])
res8: Int = 1

scala> UniqueNumberProvider.numberForClass(classOf[Int])
res9: Int = 2
```

Comment: The way you put it you can have a race condition while calling numberForClass. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah - the code as it stands isn't threadsafe (didn't want to obfuscate things by adding synchronisation :-)

Comment: The problem with this for me is the Map lookup every time I need to access the integer. At that point, I may as well use a Map to store the components. In Java for example, I would have the integer as a static field on the Component class itself, which is why I was placing it on an object.

Comment: In that case, you may have to put up with the extra typing, as things currently stand at least.

Comment: I think so. It was more a matter of curiosity than practicality, but it would have been nice regardless.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using macro in Scala 2.10. 
You can look for usage at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html

Comment: I'm not sure that I can see how to do this with macros as they currently stand (i.e. def macros). Although I'd be delighted to be proven wrong.

Comment: Could you give an example? I'm pretty sure that you need type macros for this, which are not in Scala 2.10, and which haven't even been fully designed yet, let alone implemented.